# How to get more Objects from Parse.com for an Endless ListView

Tags: android, parse-platform, logic, android-recyclerview

I have a table in Parse that stores information about places including their locations as `(ParseGeoPoint)[http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseGeoPoint.html]`. I am getting the user's current location and then querying the nearest places near the user.

My **question is** --> After I have read the first 10 items, how do I read the *next* 10 that are further way from me than the first 10 that were read? I want to read the next 10 and the 10 after that and so on because I am trying to display them in an endless `Recyclerview`.

```
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Constants.CLASS_BIZ);
        query.whereNear(Constants.CLASS_BIZ_geopoint, userLocation);
        query.setLimit(10);

        List<ParseObject> quotesList = query.find();
        Model_Business obj = new Model_Business();

        for (ParseObject qObj : quotesList) {

            if (qObj != null) {
                obj = parseObjTo_ModelBusiness(qObj);
                objs.add(obj);
            }
        }
```

I am at a loss on how to do this other than downloading the entire backend database locally, which would be inefficient and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here
https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

```
query.setSkip(10); // skip the first 10 results
```